# How to stop thread from another activity

Tags: android

I want to stop, in an Activity B, a thread that it was created in an activity A. How can I do?

Activity A

```
 Rec rec = new Rec();       
     rec.start();          
     rec.startRecording();
```

Where Rec is a thread

```
public class Rec extends Thread{

        public void Rec(Context context) {
        this.mContext = context;

    }

 @Override
 public void run(){
     .....}

 public void startRecording(){
     .....}
 public void stopRecording(){
     .....}
```

I want to use stopRecording() in an Activity B

Comment: you should use an asynctask instead

Comment: You can use a singleton for this. Store a reference to this thread in a singleton.

Comment: @Katana24 AsyncTask is a bad designed thing and should be used never IMHO. For this particular case AsyncTask is no be better than simple thread

Comment: @nickes why so if you don't mind me asking?

Comment: @Katana24 first of all, it mixes async job with result handling in a single class. Second, it prevents Activity it was started from to be GC'd while running. Then, it has cumbersome interface. And finally it is not transparent how it works for the cases of cancelling.

Comment: Try to use a `Service` to execute your thread.

Comment: @nickes interesting - would you have any further reading/resource i could examine to back this up? I don't doubt what you say but would like to weigh it up myself

Comment: Sorry, no read/links. It's just personal observations.

Comment: @nickes could you explain me how to save a reference in a Singleton? Sorry, but I'm not an expert Android Programmer.

Comment: @FlorianMacLanglade How can I do with a Service instead? thanks

Comment: Have a look : http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android-fundamentals-intentservice-basics--mobile-6183. Bind on Activity A and Activity B. When you want to stop your `Thread`, send `Broadcast`.